# custom filter to force user filling all profile property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have defined custom filter and add to global filter to apply in all actions

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    #region Implementation of IActionFilter

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        //Chech that all profile is filled
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Path-To-Create-A-Profile");
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

in asp.net mvc `Profile.GetPropertyValue("name")` gets the value of property in profile , if i want to check one or two property it has no problem , how implement best way to check that are profile property are filled? should i used flag and check `stringisemptyornull` on one by one property ?

Comment: Why do you want to use ActionFilter instead of mark all properties in profile model as [Required]? It can give you not only server validation but client as well.

Comment: can we use `[Required]` to check that one property has been filled before? see Answer that i have given . it is possible to implement with `[Required]` Filter ?

Comment: `[Required]` validates only submitted model. Sorry, it's not clear what behaviour are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i wanted to use exist model so `[Required]` no helped me , and i have written custom filter

Answer (score 0):

i just added new function that return `bool` value as below :

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        public bool checkFilledProfile() {
            return CheckFilledProfile("FirstName", "LastName", "Country", "State", "City", "Address", "PostalCode", "Phone", "Mobile", "Email");
        }

        private static bool CheckFilledProfile(params string[] properties) {
            bool returnValue = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue(properties[i]) as string))
                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Path-To-Create-A-Profile");
            }
    }
}
```

and add `[ProfileRequiredActionFilter]` in top of actions that i want to check